# Personalize Recommendations for small dataset

Tags: clustering, small-sample, recommender-system, propensity-scores, bayesian-optimization

I'm working on a recommender system for a set of niche products.  These are products that don't have a large number of customers.  Does anyone have any tips on algorithms or approaches that work well for personalizing recommendations for small sets of customers?

Comment: why would you bother? ie if ther is no demand for the product the improvement you will get is not worth the effort you put in?

Comment: @seanv507 they're high dollar items.  So we're trying to personalize recommendations for a small number of customers that we make a lot off of.

Comment: sorry to be unhrelpful, but high value, low data => human service? maybe you could quantify and give more details... one approach would be building a 'causal' model with a lot of expert input (ie people buy x because ,,,), rather than the usual collaborative filtering